# Apache2 virtualhost 403 forbidden?

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, virtualhost, http-status-code-403

I'm running ubuntu 13.04 64bit on my desktop, I installed Apache2, MySQL and PHP etc.

I wanted to have my web root in `/home/afflicto/public_html` instead of `/var/www`.
So I went along with this guide:
http://www.maketecheasier.com/install-and-configure-apache-in-ubuntu/2011/03/09
(I did everything from "configuring different sites") as I like the solution more.

**Here's what I did:**
Installed Apache2, MySQL etc..
copied `/etc/apache2/sites-avaliable/default` to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/afflicto`. Then edited it, it now looks like the following:

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/afflicto**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /home/afflicto/public_html
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /home/afflicto/public_html/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I did `sudo a2dissite default && sudo a2ensite afflicto && sudo service apache2 restart`

I created a `index.php` and `index.html` in `/home/afflicto/public_html/test/`
when accessing `localhost/test` or `localhost/test/index.html` etc, I get 403 forbidden error.

What am I doing wrong?

**update 1**
I have set the owner of the public_html directory to `www-data`.
Also `sudo chmod -R +x public_html && sudo chmod -R 777 public_html`
Still same 403 error.

Here's the output of the apache error log:

```
[Sun Jul 14 06:10:32 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: access to / denied

[Sun Jul 14 06:10:32 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: access to /favicon.ico denied
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Turns out I had to chmod not only `/home/afflicto/public_html` but also `/home/afflicto/` directory as well.

Weird.

Comment: Correct.  The apache process must have access to every directory in the path.  Additionally, the apache process requires that each directory have world-access or it won't serve the directory to the (outside) world.

Answer (score 119):

I was faced with this issue. But I didn't like the idea of changing the group of my home directory to www-data. This problem can simply be solved by modifying the configuration file for the virtualHost.
Simply configure the Directory tag to include these

```
<Directory "your directory here">
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

The `Require all granted` is a new feature I guess; having a default value of `denied`.

see this page for further info: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory

Comment: Apparently Order and Allow are not required for 2.4?

Comment: Situations exist where `Require all granted` might still not solve the problem. Cases where the files are to be served from a user directory [which might be encrypted]. In which case you need to do a `chmod +x` on the user directory. I'm adding this comment because I encountered this error "access denied because search permissions are missing"; the chmod +x on my home dir helped out. I'm not sure if this is very safe but my home dir is encrypted.

Comment: Thank you, I was stuck with this error for half an hour before reading your solution!

Comment: in  my case I also needed to do this "chmod +x /home/(username)", http://www.andrewklau.com/permission-denied-because-search-permissions-are-missing-on-a-component-of-the-path/

Comment: Options  +Indexes should be added on apache 2.4.18+ if you want to show the folders

Comment: thank you I only change Allow from all

Answer (score 1):

These options worked for me:

```
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride All   
 Require all granted
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another answer intending to add a simpler explanation. Let's say you want to serve a file named "main" which is in the `/var/www/testwebsite` directory(the DocumentRoot of an already configured & enabled virtual host). Now assume we want the Apache web server to only have access to the "main" file and not other files(e.g. main might be an entry point to our web app), then it means that the apache web server has to be the owner of that file. so `chown www-data:www-data /var/www/testwebsite/main` must do it. (notice: `www-data` is both the name of the user and the name of the group that apache uses when interacting with other files(actually, on distributions other than Ubuntu, this might be a different name, in which case it can simply be looked up in the `apache2.conf` as well)). Also in case the "main" file doesn't have the permission to be read/executed, it must be granted to the apache's user and group: `chmod 770 /var/www/testwebsite/main`. This gives the user(www-data) and the group(www-data) who are owners of the file "main" these permissions: read/write/execute(4+2+1=7), and gives other users no permissions. Now that single file(main) can be run by the Apache while we can have any other strict level of restriction on all other files in the `/var/www/testwebsite` directory.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this exact issue for hours, and what finally solved it for me is adding a slash after the directory inside of `apache2.conf`.

`<Directory /dir>` -> `<Directory /dir/>`

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your server configuration

```
<Directory /home/afflicto/public_html>
   AllowOverride none
   Require all denied
</Directory>
```

If www-root:www-root does not have permission to access, it may not work. I got a very similar problem when setting up apache2, and this fixed it for me.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

None of the above works, it should be a path problem in site.config or apache2.config, go to the folder and copy the address URL and paste, restart the apache, and check